# How to install MySQL with apt and configure mysql root user with auth_socket on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, installation, root, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to write a server-setup bash script and I'm running into an inconsistency issue. On some servers when I install mysql using apt, the root user is created with `auth_socket` authentication. On other servers, the root user is created with a password and `caching_sha2_password` authentication. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling MySQL to determine what I did wrong but there are no prompts. How can I consistently do the install with the root user being created with `auth_socket` authentication?